# How to change name of a folder inside tar.gz before decompressing?

Tags: linux, command-line, tar

I have a tar.gz called "first.tar.gz". Inside it I have only one folder called "first" (no other folders or files). I want to decompress the tar.gz, so the folder "first" renames to "second".

I tried this:

`tar -zxf first.tar.gz --transform s/first/second/`

but it didn't work for me. I didn't get any errors / response, it just extracted the "first" folder without renaming.
The version of tar is 1.26

Comment: What is the output of `tar -ztf first.tar.gz`?

Comment: The output is ```first/```

Comment: I created a file that gives the same output from `tar -ztf`. Your `--transform` works in tar 1.30.

Comment: You accepted an answer that does not solve the *described* problem. If it solves your problem then it means the current state of the question does not really reflect the problem. "I tried `tar -zxf …`" should be "I tried `tar -vzxf …`" and "it just extracted" should be "it printed". Then the answer would fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `--transform` with GNU `tar` and ask for verbose output with `-v`, the pathnames you see outputted are the *un-transformed* pathnames.

GNU `tar` will transform the pathnames according to your `--transform` expression but will not report these in the output unless you use the option `--show-transformed-names`.

Example:

```bash
$ tree
.
`-- archive.tar

0 directories, 1 file
```

```bash
$ gtar -t -f archive.tar
first/
first/dir/
first/dir/first.txt
first/dir/file
```

```bash
$ gtar -xv -f archive.tar --transform='s/first/second/'
first/
first/dir/
first/dir/first.txt
first/dir/file
```

Note how the above command reports the pathnames stored in the archive.  Below, we see that the pathnames were transformed appropriately.

```bash
$ tree
.
|-- archive.tar
`-- second
    `-- dir
        |-- file
        `-- first.txt

2 directories, 3 files
```